# How to change time and date language to English?

Tags: 16.04, settings

I do not know how it comes, but my calendar(upper right corner) is in Polish. How to change this to English?

Comment: only that text is affected and all the other text is in English?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Yes,everything else is in English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

data utility uses variable LC_TIME to know what language of days to use. If you want to know if this is really the issue, try:

```
echo $LC_TIME
```

then if you dont want to mess up anything, but still have different language in your script just change it in your script like

```
LC_TIME=en_US.utf8
```

Comment: as said in the other answer, the file in question is `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: just to clarify, if you want to change it permanently, `export LC_TIME=en_US.utf8` ...put it into ~/.bashrc (your shell's init file) or ~/.profile to apply it everywhere on start

Answer (score 11):

If everything except date is in English, then there is a high chance that the value of `LC_TIME` is something wrong, use `localectl` command to change it to your desired locale:

```
sudo localectl set-locale LC_TIME=en_US.utf8
```

or `en_GB.utf8` for UK.

You can also place `LC_TIME=en_US.utf8` at this file `/etc/default/locale` manually if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

The default `locale` file location here:
**/etc/default**

First install: `nautilus-admin` then logOut and logIn.

Then go to **/etc/default**.

Right click on `locale` and ***Edit As Administrator***.

Edit `locale` file like this and save:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Done. Now log-out and log-in.

Answer (score 0):

Select the system settings "window". Click on Language Support. In the Regional Format tab set the preferred language. I had same problem when I first set clock wound up in Spanish. You will need to restart after change to take affect.