# Terminal won't open after localectl command change

Tags: gnome-terminal, locale

I had [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918482/how-to-change-time-and-date-language-to-english), I have followed this advice, but after the restart terminal can not be opened.

If I run `gnome-terminal` from xterm:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Tactory0:Error calling StartServiceByName for org.name.Terminal:GDBUs
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Setting the locale shouldn't create any problem. Have you tried with CTRL+ALT+T or searching terminal in the dash? What happens exactly?

Comment: @MichaelBay Nothing happens,I have used this command last 10 years.

Comment: @MichaelBay I can see terminal from the dash,but can not open it.

Comment: So, neither method works? If so something is definitely wrong but I don't know what can be, sorry.

Comment: Switch to a `tty` using ctrl+alt+f1, then open this file  `sudo nano  /etc/default/locale` make sure there is only `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` save and reboot. let me know if it worked so I post it as an answer ;)

Comment: @Ravexina I have only that line exactly,no terminal again.

Comment: @MikiBelavista so it hard to say that it's related to locales, are you able to open`xterm` ?

Comment: @Ravexina Yes,from dash,xterm no problems.

Comment: @MikiBelavista open `xterm` in xterm type-in `gnome-terminal` to run default terminal, does it give you any error?

Comment: @Ravexina Takea look at my edit,please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59254/discussion-between-ravexina-and-mikibelavista).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's see which locales are enabled on your Ubuntu:

```
grep -v '^#' /etc/locale.gen
```

you should get something similar to:

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
...
```

use an editor to disable unnecessary locales by commenting them, also if your output does not contains `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` then uncoment that line to enable it.

Now run:

```
sudo locale-gen
sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8
```

then reboot the system.

Comment: Great answer. Worked for me. But, out of curiosity, do you know how to resolve this problem in a preseed file? I am doing an unattended (automated) install, and I thought that I was properly setting the locale, but obviously not. Of course I could run these two commands at the end of each preseed file, but I am setting up a PXE install to install many versions of linux, and I wouldn't want to have to remember to put this "fix" at the end of each preseed. Thanks again

Comment: @JabariDash Unfortunately I'm not familiar with preseed files.

Comment: Usually you won't need a reboot, just `sudo systemctl restart gdm` or `sudo service gdm restart`

Comment: @foo some services might be still running and not effected by restarting `gdm`. Though it might work in almost most of the cases, a reboot is the way to not get  surprised.