# Cannot open Gnome Terminal after "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bash"

Tags: command-line, locale

Please help a begginer. I tried to change my terminal output language with this command I found online "LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bash" (from Finnish to English).

However after that I cannot open the Gnome terminal, not with Ctrl+Alt+T, not from the menu... I can still open urxvt. Any tips on how to correct this?

Things I've tried:

-The answer from here: [Terminal won't open after localectl command change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918558/terminal-wont-open-after-localectl-command-change)

-changing the language back to Finnish, with the same command, and from the system settings.

Just in case it might have something to do with locales, here are some more info:

locale -a output:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
fi_FI.utf8
POSIX
```

locale output:

```
LANG=fi_FI.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fi:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fi_FI.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

localetcl stauts output:

```
System Locale: LANG=fi_FI.UTF-8
VC Keymap: n/a
X11 Layout: fi
X11 Model: pc10
```

Pleas help, I am a beginner and I am most familiar with the Gnome terminal, I really want it to work :(

Comment: It is only gnome-terminal you want in English? Then you should probably start it up with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bash gnome-terminal`. The locale en_US.UTF-8 should be available on your system.

Comment: Yes that is what I tried to do. But right now I don't care about the language if I just get it working again :(

Comment: I guess can use xterm? Install it, then launch gnome-terminal from the command line: the output might give a clue to what is wrong.

Comment: Try to drop that trailing "bash" at the end of the command.